# How to store custom css . js files in laravel and calling it in views

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel

I'm having a view file which includes css and js file itself . 
Now I want to use the same css and js file in another view . How can I use the same css and js in other view? Is there a way to store them in a single file and access it from anywhere?

Comment: store it as file in public directory and access from there

Comment: I've read something about storing the files in same view and we can access it through @ extends and @ section. But I don't really know to use it .

Comment: Take a look at [template inheritance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#template-inheritance) if you want to extend a view

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#stacks hope this will also help you

Comment: If your first view includes that css and js file what's stopping you from including it in any other view using the exact same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your custom css and js by using

You can read the documentation in laravel official docs.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade

```
@push('styles')
   ...
@endpush

@push('scripts')
     <script src="/example.js"></script>
@endpush
```